# When the limit isn't provided, how do I know when to use $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ over $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$?

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I am unsure of which to pick when trying to solve a problem. For example; I was given the problem:

> Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point
>
> $$y=4x-3x^2, \qquad (2,-4)$$

which was then solved by the $(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$ formula.

I was then given the problem;

> Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point;
> $$y = \frac{2x+1}{x+2}, \qquad (1,1)$$

which was solved using the $(f(x)-f(a))(x-a)$.

So, how does one pick which formula to use to get the correct answer?

Comment: The two are the same: in the $a+h$ formula, let $x=a+h$; then $\lim_{x\to a}$ becomes $\lim_{h\to 0}$.

Comment: They are the same. But I want to say something else: usually in this kind of problems, you are not expected to find the derivative using the definition. Instead, you can simply state that "if $y=4x-3x^2$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=4-6x$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions are equivalent, so either will give you the correct answer. I don't think there's a hard rule about when to use either definition.

If you try one definition and it seems confusing, then try the other definition.